# sound decay calculus question

Tags: calculus

[image]

Question part d) I could not do. It requires you to take the expression part b), and let $a = \tan(\pi/12)$, let $y' = 0$ and then solve for $x$. This is to find the stationary points which Qd) wants.

Working...

$0=-2e^{-x\tan \frac \pi {2}}(\sin x+[\tan \frac \pi {12}]\cos x)$

$-\sin x=[\tan \frac{\pi}{12}]\cos x$

$-\tan x=\tan \frac{\pi}{12}$

And then I had no idea what to do. I would have taken the tan inverse if not for the annoying negative sign on LHS.

UPDATE: Credit to @Actually Fritz, I no longer have part d problems.

$\tan (\pi-x) = tan (\pi/12)$
taking tan inverse....
$x=11\pi$ on 12 and since tan is a periodic function, the solutions occur every $\pi$ interval. which explains the sequence the question wanted me to arrive at in d).

I still have the next problem though.

For part g) I did not understand how to express "where y increases at an increasing/decreasing rate". (though I am aware that it involves looking at the slope is up and concave up/down).From the graph of the function, there are many points that exhibit this behaviour. So how could I possibly compare ratios of "where behaviour $A$ at multiple points" to "where behaviour $B$ at multiple points". The question doesn't make logical sense to me. If A happens at $x=2$ and $x=3$ and $B$ happens at $x=4$ and $x=5$, then which ratio am I comparing? The ratio $x=2$ to $x=4$? Or the ratio $x=2$ to $x=5$? No logical sense to me.

Comment: what about using $\tan(\pi - x) = - \tan x$?

Comment: for your second question, you have to compute the ratio of the measure of the set where $y' \geq 0$ and $y'' \geq 0$ and the measure of the set where $y' \geq 0$ and $y'' < 0.$

Comment: @ActuallyFritz For first part, I use that technique and I wind up with x=11pi on 12. and obviously tan (pi) is periodic for every pi Thank you.  I had one question though...is it safe to divide by cos here though? Because what if I remove a solution?

Comment: @ActuallyFritz the problem is...what is that measure? It says "where" implying location x. But if that were the case, the as I explain above then the question becomes nonsensical

Comment: No, it does not become nonsensical and I urge you to become acquainted with a little bit of [measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)). You will obtain the union of some intervals as your answer and obviously the measure of an interval is its length. You will then have to compute the limit of the ratio of the measures of say $[-n, n]$ with the corresponding intervals as $n \to \infty.$ I have no idea what you mean by "removing solutions" or why it wouldn't be safe to divide by a quantity that is obviously non-zero.